# Is it possible to answer and hangup using rest API in Sinch?

Tags: android, sinch

Currently I'm trying to integrate Sinch with Appcelerator Android, to make my life lot easier, is it possible to answer or hangup just by calling a REST API ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appcelerator or another JavaScript based sdk is not supported by Sinch. 
It may work with our JSSDK but there is no Rest api calls to accomplish this. There is a lot of processing going on the client side in voice calls so you will need a native SDK or you can try JSSDK but we do not officially support it